# How to pass object between directives AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

If I define/instantiate an object `foo` inside the link function of directive A. What's a way to access the same object from the link function of a separate directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [documenation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> The controller is instantiated before the pre-linking phase and it is
>   shared with other directives (see require attribute). This allows the
>   directives to communicate with each other and augment each other's
>   behavior.

This means that to share data between two directives on the same object or it's children, you'll need to expose foo inside directive A controller, injected with `require` option in directive B.

The directives would look like this:

```
.directive("dirA", function () {
    return {
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, controller) {
            controller.foo = $attrs.dirA;
        }
    }
})
.directive("dirB", function () {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, $el, $attr, controller) {
            $scope.shared = controller.foo;
        },
        require: "dirA"
    }
})
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/GdFcp/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll add it here.

Some additional info for someone struggling with the same issue. It depends on where the directives are used in relation to each other.

> The ^ prefix means that this directive searches for the controller on
>   its parents (without the ^ prefix, the directive would look for the
>   controller on just its own element).